# Java in Visual Studio

Tags: java, visual-studio

Is it possible to program Java in Visual Studio?

```
    if(some plugins == true)
    {
       System.out.println("Please Tell Me");
    }else{
       System.err.println("Thank You Fro Help");
    }
```

Comment: No, basically. Use Eclipse, IntelliJ or Netbeans instead.

Answer (score 0):

You now write an application that will be executed under Java Virtual Machine using Visual Studio.

What you can do is to develop using Java syntax using [Visual J#] that will be supported to 2017. The application will be executed on .Net Framework.